# how to ignore (tags,scripts) in an ajax call. for json use

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to ignore tags like divs and scripts and just get the json texts.
my ajax call doesnt work if i have none json format texts. but i think it would be pointless if you have a page with pure json format only.

#### My ajax call

```
   $.ajax({ 
          url: "secpage.html",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#load").html(data);
           alert(data);
       }
   });
```

#### My page to be returned

```
 <script></script>          
 {"msg" : "Hello"}
```

I want to igonre those script tags and just have the json text. plss help.

Comment: Which do you think it is pointless to have json only?

Comment: JSON is typically returned by itself. It's just data in an object-literal format, so you typically don't want it mixed with markup.

Comment: I know Jontahtan. what i mean is that data returned includes the scripts tag.

Comment: @TimWolla what if i need to use javascript to manipulate the data and pass it as json.

Comment: The JSON-handling code should be in the scripts that are already loaded!

Comment: ?? can you show some example code?

Comment: $("#load").html(data).substring(17);

Comment: hmm.. ok i get your point guys thankx @Gerben and Timwolla. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
$.ajax({ 
      url: "secpage.html",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success:  function(data) {
         var newdata='';
         data=data.split('\n');
         for (var i in data) {
              if (i.charAt(0)=='{'){
                  newdata+=i + '\n';
               }
          }
          alert(newdata);
   }
```

});